# Not able to build my project in simulator, Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, textures, xcode10, asyncdisplaykit

I am facing a strange issue:

I updated Texture to 2.7 in Pods
And I am using Xcode 10.

The issue is that I am able to build the project successfully in `iPhone` real device.
But its not building in `simulator`. The following error is coming:

`Thread-local storage is not supported for the current target` in file `ASAssert.m`

Can anyone help?

What I have already tried:
I tried setting the below command in podfile

```
configuration.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
```

But when I use this, I get the below error:

```
No such module 'AsyncDisplayKit'
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18356

Comment: there is no solution provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its fixed now.
I pointed my pod to master and run pod install.
And its working fine now.